# SearchView с выпадающим списком

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Хотелось бы реализовать SearchView с выпадающим списком, примерно как это сделано на GooglePlay:

[image: SearchView_GooglePlay]

У меня есть адаптер написанный по примеру из этой статьи: http://habrahabr.ru/post/260045/

т.е. мне нужно передать текст запроса в метод searchAnker который вернет курсор.

Код searchAnker:

```
public Cursor searchAnker(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        inputText = inputText.toLowerCase();
        String query = "SELECT docid as _id," + KEY_INPUT + "," + KEY_ANKER + " FROM " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_INPUT + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

SearchView в данный момент реализован с помощью android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Вот код xml:

```
    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
            sabd:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
            sabd:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Код Java:

```
    ...
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();

            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
            searchView.setQueryHint("Поиск");
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        try {
                cursor = searchDbAdapter.searchAnker(searchView.getQuery().toString());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] from = new String[]{SearchDbAdapter.KEY_INPUT};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.search_query_text};
            cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.search_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    ...

    @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s){
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            return false;
        }
    ...
```

Каким образом можно реализовать такой поиск с помощью этого searchView? Может быть есть какие то примеры?

Спасибо.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, можно создать SimpleCursorAdapter передать в него layout который будет выступать в качестве итема выпадающего списка, курсор, который возвращает метод searchAnker и столбцы сопоставления. Далее нужно передать cursorAdapter в метод setSuggestionsAdapter и типа, вроде как, все должно быть в окей... но не выходит... Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?) Обновил топик, добавил код который наваял...

Comment: Я конечно не уверен на счет вообще всего кода) но самое большое сомнение вызывает вот эта строчка - searchView.getQuery().toString(), вроде как должно возвращать набранный запрос и преобразовывать в строку...